# How can I forward a message that received a server to another server in Netty (Java)?

Tags: java, jboss, connection, netty, nio

I have some clients, they communicate with one server and I need that server forward the message to another second server. Then, receive the message from the second server and send to the client.

With this method, I achieve connecting to the second server but it doesn't receive the message and throws me the following exception:

EXCEPTION: java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException. java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) throws IOException, Exception {
        response = "hola" + "\r\n";
        Main.creaLog("Mensaje recibido del conc: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        Main.creaLog("Mensaje enviado al servidor : " + response);


        ClientBootstrap bootstrap1 = new ClientBootstrap(
        new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

        // Configure the pipeline factory.
        //bootstrap1.setPipelineFactory(new CLIENTE.ClientePipelineFactory());
        bootstrap1.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
         public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
                return Channels.pipeline(new ClienteHandler());
         }
        });

        final ChannelFuture future = bootstrap1.connect(new InetSocketAddress("172.16.10.14", 12355));

        Channel channel = future.getChannel();

        if (channel.isWritable()) {
            ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = channel.write(e.getMessage().toString() + "\r\n");
        }
        close = true;


    // We do not need to write a ChannelBuffer here.
    // We know the encoder inserted at TelnetPipelineFactory will do the conversion.
    ChannelFuture future = e.getChannel().write(response + "\r\n");
    //CIERRA LA CONEXION
    if (close) {
        future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I'm very thanksful if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Netty Proxy example](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.html)

Right now, you are basically attempting to connect to the remote server on every message that you receive. This probably isn't what you want. You might want to connect to the remote server only once (i.e. outbound channel in Netty proxy example) and forward a new incoming message to that specific channel.